# Uploading a website to a server steps?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server

Hi guys, I have a nodejs website and I am using mongodb database in this application. My question is, when I upload this site to a server, is it important that server supports nodejs and mongodb? I mean, can I upload this app to every server or Do I need to supporting?

And second question is, can you write  the step of uploading database and web site to a server and Do I need two servers or one for upload database and website are they seperate or together?

These questions could be dumb but I am junior developer and I don't have any idea about that problems. So, please light me up, every answers are precious.

Have good days guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

A site may offer vm hosting. This is where you choose your own server to build on the cloud and manually install node js and databases etc.

Or you can go for a package where they do the complicated stuff for you and you simply upload your zip file or copy database across. E.g Amazon elastic beanstalk can be configured for node js. Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) for hosting a db.

Microsoft, Google and others all have their own could services platforms

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I understand it, this is for cloud servers. So can I  upload my nodejs  and mongodb application to every server, for example if server machine's operating system is windows or linux? Is it important to be open source server machine system?

Comment: A server is just another term for a computer that is hosting the application. You only need one server. Cloud server means its managed remotely online.

You only need to worry about what the operating system is if you want your own vm. As i mentioned above elastic beanstalk etc means you dont have to worry about the server